# Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python-3.x, access-denied, python-tesseract

When I try to execute this code, I get this error (snapshot in attached file) : # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe. PermissionError: ][WinError 5] Access is denied ' . Is there any solution for this. Thanks.

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files'
img = Image.open("one.jpg")
width, height = img.size
new_size = width*6, height*6
img = img.resize(new_size, Image.LANCZOS)
img = img.convert('L')
img = img.point(lambda x: 0 if x < 155 else 255, '1')
imagetext = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print (imagetext)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files'
```

For sure,you can not access this file without Administrator authority.

There are two way to do this:

1. add your `tesseract` to your system PATH(recommend).
2. Run the py file as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick answer. Yes, it is good to understand that I should be an administrator if I want to execute this code. Could you please let me know how add 'tesseract" to my system PATH (recommonded) and execute this code, if I am not an administrator. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your solution. After adding `tesseract` to my system PATH, tt helps to lead the real solution by adding the executable file in the path like: `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\tesseract.exe`

Comment: Now you use `tesseract --version ` in cmd,what will happened?

Comment: Actually,after you success to add tesseract to your system PATH,you needn't to use `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\tesseract.exe`

Comment: when I used tesseract --version in cmd, I go this following:tesseract v5.0.0-alpha.20200223
 leptonica-1.78.0
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.3) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE
 Found libarchive 3.3.2 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.2.3 bz2lib/1.0.6 liblz4/1.7.5
 Found libcurl/7.59.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2o (WinSSL) zlib/1.2.11 WinIDN libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.31.0       

Now, it is working fine after adding tesseract in my system PATH and used "tesseract.exe" in the python code. Missed anything?

Comment: That's right,you needn't to use `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\tesseract.exe'` now in your code.